# Assume by/by way of /toward contradiction

Tags: mathematics

What is the correct/best way to start a proof by contradiction? The following three ways are quite common:

- Assume by contradiction that...
- Assume, by way of contradiction, that...
- Assume toward contradiction that...

Is there any preference? Specifically, are any of the grammatically or semantically incorrect?

Also, are there other, preferable ways?

Comment: I would not use any of these. I would use a form more like "Assume the following, which will be shown to lead to a contradiction."

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a standard jargon in the mathematical community (at least in my experience). It's slightly too elaborate to start a proof this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematician here. The 2nd item in your list of suggestions is by far the best. The other two sound a little strange to me, and may very well be grammatically incorrect.

I will suggest a similar phrase: **"Assume, for sake of contradiction, that...."**  I use this in the courses I teach, and my students and I end up using the acronym **AFSOC** as a shorthand.

I like this phrase because it accurately conveys what is going on in a proof by contradiction. That is, it really says, "I'm going to assume this is true right now, *not* because I really believe it, but because I will use it to find a contradiction."

Comment: Would you say that the others are incorrect grammatically, or just don't convey the idea? (because judging by the amount of times they appear, in google at least, the first one is actually more popular than the second. But this doesn't mean it's correct, as most documents are not written by grammar-conscious people).

Comment: I am not confident enough to say that they are *definitely incorrect*, grammatically, but they "sound strange" enough to me that I would not use them myself.